# What do we in cases where users answer questions that have been marked as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I have just marked a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434505/how-to-install-gnome-desktop-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts) as a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome) and after sometime I have found other users answering it with the same answers like in the linked duplicate question.

How can I handle such cases?

---

I think it's related to users who just post questions without searching first to see if the question has been asked before.

Comment: flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @AvinashRaj flags take sometime before they are approved and in that time alot can happen - in this case, answers have been given.

Comment: if you flag it to mod attention, they mark that question as dupe immediately or maybe the chance of deleting that answer.So no more votes on that question and answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have flagged the question as a duplicate, leave it alone for others to do their work. It will remain open for answers until the question is closed as a duplicate. If you think the answers are an exact duplicate of the answers posted on the original question, flag it for moderators' attention.

Moderators and >10k users will see if the answers posted on the duplicate question is exactly similar to the answers on the original post and may delete it if they find that they are exactly the same.

IMO, downvoting should be used only if you think the answer is useless for the question in consideration. Flags are appropriate here.

Comment: Also, feel free to downvote the question, if it didn't show research effort.